# Filter display of Tkinter Treeview using a function

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a Tkinter Treeview, which I import .csv data into. I then manually assign  `Not Started` `Yet To Arrive` to the row of columnn `Current Status` via an `.option menu` drop down. What is the best way to create a function to filter the treeview and only show rows with `Not Started` in the `Current Status` column? I have so far explored options using the following doc. Trying `.detach` but I dont think this appropriate for my application. https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/ttk-Treeview.html

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.ttk as tkrttk
from PIL import Image, ImageFont, ImageTk
import csv
from tkinter import filedialog

root = tk.Tk()
button_1 = Button(root, text="Not Started", command = "SomeFunction")
button_1.place(x=0, y=0, height=50, width=150)

treetime = tkrttk.Treeview(root)
treetime['columns'] = ("Column2", "Column3", "Column4", "Column5",
                       "Column6", "Column7", "Column8", "Column9", "Column10", "Column11")

column_list = list(treetime ['columns'])
treetime.place(x=0, y=60)
treetime.column("#0", width=0)
treetime.column("Column2", width=80, minwidth=50)
treetime.column("Column3", width=80, minwidth=50)
treetime.column("Column4", width=80, minwidth=50)
treetime.column("Column5", width=80, minwidth=50)
treetime.column("Column6", width=80, minwidth=100)
treetime.column("Column7", width=300, minwidth=100)
treetime.column("Column8", width=200, minwidth=100)
treetime.column("Column9", width=200, minwidth=100)
treetime.column("Column10", width=300, minwidth=100)
treetime.column("Column11", width=200, minwidth=100)

treetime.heading('#0', text="", anchor=tk.W)
treetime.heading('Column2', text="Ro Number", anchor=tk.W)
treetime.heading('Column3', text="Date In", anchor=tk.W)
treetime.heading('Column4', text="Time In", anchor=tk.W)
treetime.heading('Column5', text="Time Out", anchor=tk.W)
treetime.heading('Column6', text="Rego Number", anchor=tk.W)
treetime.heading('Column7', text="Customer Name", anchor=tk.W)
treetime.heading('Column8', text="Vehicle Make", anchor=tk.W)
treetime.heading('Column9', text="Vehicle Model", anchor=tk.W)
treetime.heading('Column10', text="Job Description", anchor=tk.W)
treetime.heading('Column11', text="Current Status", anchor=tk.W)

def select_input_file():
            global input_file_path
            input_file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(
            filetypes=(("CSV files", "*.csv"),))
            with open(input_file_path) as csv_file:
              rdr = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
              for row in rdr:
                 RoNumber = row['Ro Number']
                 DateIn = row['Date In']
                 TimeIn = row['Time In']
                 TimeOut = row['Time Out']
                 RegoNumber = row['Rego Number']
                 CustomerName = row['Customer Name']
                 VehicleMake = row['Vehicle Make']
                 VehicleModel = row['Vehicle Model']
                 JobDescription = row['Job Description']
                 CurrentStatus = row['Current Status']

                 treetime.insert("", 0, values=(RoNumber, DateIn, TimeIn, TimeOut, RegoNumber,
                                           CustomerName, VehicleMake, VehicleModel, JobDescription, CurrentStatus))

StatusList = [
    "Not Started",
    "Yet to Arrive",
]

Status = StringVar()
Status.set(0)

def set_status(value):
    row = treetime.focus()
    treetime.set(row, 'Column11', value)


def set_status(value):
    row = treetime.focus()
    if row:
        treetime.set(row, 'Column11', value)

drop=tkrttk.OptionMenu(root, Status, "Select Status", *StatusList, command=set_status)
drop.place(x=1440, y=0, height=50, width=150)

drop=tkrttk.OptionMenu(root, Status, "Select Status", *StatusList, command=set_status)
drop.place(x=1440, y=0, height=50, width=150)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I think you need to clear the treeview first and insert the filtered items into it again.

Comment: ok, possibly using `selection_remove()`?

Comment: Should be `treetime.delete(*treetime.get_children())`.